# Could not find application with identifier “com.apple.itunes.connect.ApplicationLoader” when running Validation

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to run Validation on our build machines. Our build machines don't have iOS SDK and Xcode installed. We copy/sync them from SCM. Running Validation on them fails:

```
$ <some-path>/ios-sdk-4.3/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/Validation -verbose my-app.ipa 
Validating my-app.ipa -verbose warnings
2012-02-03 15:11:14.314 Validation[26576:903] Could not find application with identifier “com.apple.itunes.connect.ApplicationLoader” (err = -10814)
warning: Application validation was skipped.
```

I think its because Validation is not able to find Application Loader. Application Loader is at:

```
<some-path>/ios-sdk-4.3/Applications/Utilities/Application\ Loader.app
```

How can I run Validation without installing Xcode/iOS SDK?

Comment: So what was your question? "Why can't I launch an app on a machine that doesn't have it installed?"

Comment: The question is how can I run Validation without installing xcode.

Comment: @NickLockwood BTW, I copied the xcode installation from a machine on which it was installed. The copied xcode works for building/compiling the app.